# iphone MultipeerConnectivity lag

Tags: iphone, ios7

I am using MultipeerConnectivity framework for connecting two iOS devices in my app. I am able to connect two device using this framework but it is taking almost one minute to send an event  from one device to other. I am testing this on simulator right now so I am not sure if that is causing the delay.

Should I be using a different framework for passing value of 2-3 variables from one device o another so that it is fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MultiPeerConnectivity framework by default the callback for the receiver happens on a background thread When you receive data from the session delegate, you need to do your work on the main thread:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    //do your work here
}];
```